# how to replace 'a' character with 'z' only if 'a' is at first position in word using javascript

Tags: javascript, string, replace

i want  to replace string from

"I am master at string" to "I zm master zt string"

I don not want to replace all character 'a' or only first character i want to replace only those character which starts with 'a' if word have 'a' in between it should not replaced

in string there is method called replace() but with replace we can only change first occurance  or using with regx g we can replace all the character but i want to replace  all 'a' character with 'z' , only if 'a' is at first position in word. how can do with javascript

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Hint: Use the `\b` word boundary pattern.

Comment: split the whole string by space, iterate over each word, check if first letter is 'a' and if it is, change it

Comment: `\b` matches a word boundary. https://regex101.com/r/3BYvVA/1

Comment: There is also the method `replaceAll`

Comment: replaceAll is mostly useful for plain strings. If you're already reaching for regexp anyway, just add `g`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can preserve case if you transform the matched letter to a char code, add 25, and convert back into a letter.

**Note:** The `\b` (word boundary) before the target letter means start of word, and the `ig` flags toggle case-insensitive and global replace repectively.

```js
console.log(
  'I am master at string'
    .replace(/\b(a)/ig, (g) =>
      String.fromCharCode(g.charCodeAt(0) + 25)));
```

Here is a functional example:

```js
// Look Ma, no magic numbers!
const
  CHAR_LOWER_A = 'a'.charCodeAt(0), //  97
  CHAR_LOWER_Z = 'z'.charCodeAt(0), // 122
  CHAR_UPPER_A = 'A'.charCodeAt(0), //  65
  CHAR_UPPER_Z = 'Z'.charCodeAt(0); //  90

const subFirstLetters = (str, from, to) => {
  const
    targetOffset = to.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - CHAR_LOWER_A,
    expression = new RegExp(`\\b(${from})`, 'ig');
  return str.replace(expression, (g) => {
    const sourceOffset = g.charCodeAt(0);
    if (sourceOffset >= CHAR_UPPER_A && sourceOffset <= CHAR_UPPER_Z) {
      return String.fromCharCode(targetOffset + CHAR_UPPER_A);
    } else if (sourceOffset >= CHAR_LOWER_A && sourceOffset <= CHAR_LOWER_Z) {
      return String.fromCharCode(targetOffset + CHAR_LOWER_A);
    }
    return g;
  });
};

// I am the Waster of strings, wwahaha!
console.log(subFirstLetters('I am the Master of strings, mwahaha!', 'm', 'w'));
```

Comment: This answer would be improved by explaining how you use `replace` to replace all matches, as the asker had an issue with that while trying to solve their issue.

Comment: @Feathercrown improved reponse

Comment: Excellent improvements, and nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of the `split()` method to break the string into words, and then iterate through the words to check if the first character is 'a'. If it is, replace the 'a' with 'z'. Finally, use the `join()` method to reassemble the string.

```js
function replaceFirstChar(inputStr, searchChar, replaceChar) {
  // Split the string into words
  const words = inputStr.split(" ");

  // Iterate through the words and replace the first character if it matches searchChar
  const updatedWords = words.map(word => {
    if (word[0] === searchChar) {
      return replaceChar + word.slice(1);
    }
    return word;
  });

  // Join the updated words back into a single string
  return updatedWords.join(" ");
}

const inputString = "I am master at string";
const outputString = replaceFirstChar(inputString, 'a', 'z');
console.log(outputString); // Output: "I zm master zt string"
```

edit:

as @evolutionxbox points out, you can simply use the following regular expression:

```js
console.log("I am master at string".replaceAll(/\ba/g, 'z'));
```

Comment: why not `"I am master at string".replaceAll(/\ba/g, 'z')`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Wouldn't that also replace the word boundary?

Comment: @Feathercrown I'm not sure replacing a word boundary is possible. Not without removing the space at least

Comment: @evolutionxbox I updated my answer to include your solution as well

Comment: thank you @steev I was looking for simple approach I thought I would have to use \w instead of \b but now I knew \b and \w are diffence of them

Answer (score 0):

Approach without regex. You can use `.split` got get an array of words. Use map with a condition (ternary syntax): if a word starts with "a",  "z" is added as the first letter using a string literal and the the rest of the word using `substring`. Otherwise the word is unchanged. At the end, array is converted to string with `join`.

```js
const replace = input => input
  .split(' ')
  .map(word => (word.startsWith('a') ? `z${word.substring(1)}` : word))
  .join(' ');

const input = "I am master at string";
const output = replace(input);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: i wanted simple approarch but thanks this also works